# Using pytorch built in derivative as part of custom autograd function

Tags: pytorch, autograd

I'm looking to implement a custom autograd. A function where the backward pass is a mix of a custom function and the derivative of a function which torch should be able to find by itself.

For a simple example, say I wanted to create a function for y = x * exp(x)

```
def custom_function(torch.autograd.Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, x):
       ctx.save_for_backward(x)
       return x * exp(x)

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):
       x = ctx.saved_tensors[0]

       custom_derivative = x * [d/dx torch.exp(x)] + torch.exp(x)
       return grad_output * custom_derivative
```

How would one call the derivative of a known pytorch function in the backward pass?

Comment: I think it is not possible to directly call the backward function. However, if you use your custom function and a function of PyTorch, during backward pass, PyTorch will combine the gradients from both the function. Let's say in your example, `exp(x)` is a PyTorch function and you have a custom function `f(x)`. So you can use `f(x) * exp(x)` with `f(x)` is implemented as you showed. PyTorch knows how to combine gradients for the multiplication operation.

Comment: Do you want to call the `backward()` method explicitly (no need, pytorch does that once you initiate `backward()` on some expression down the graph) or do you want to see its output? Maybe you could clarify this.

Comment: What I ultimately want to achieve is to implement the gradient updates from this paper 

Implicit Reparameterization Gradients
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.08498.pdf  

In equation 6, z is the output of some function. 
The backward pass is custom made and combines the derivatives of two known pytorch functions.